# Prove $f(x) = |\cos x|^{1/2}$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$ or not

Tags: real-analysis

Can I use the definition to explain whether $f$ is uniform or not?
Second if not can I use the property if the derivatve of function is bounded then its uniform?

Comment: Unfortunately, the derivative of that function is _not_ bounded. Do you have other theorems that conclude that something is uniformly continuous?

Comment: The method is 1) defintion

Comment: @Evariste You are right, I was mistaken. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The composition of uniformly continuous maps is again uniformly continuous.

The maps
$$\cos:\mathbb{R}\to[-1,1]$$
$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{abs}:[-1,1]\to[0,1]$$
$$\,\text{sqrt}:[0,1]\to[0,1]$$
are all uniformly continuous, hence your function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ given by $f(x)=|\cos(x)|^{1/2}$ is equal to the composition

$$\text{sqrt}\circ\text{abs}\circ\cos:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$$
and is thus uniformly continuous

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in this case $f$ is not derivable, also if you remove from $\mathbb{R}$ the poits of the set $E:=\left\{\dfrac{2k+1}{2} \pi : k\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ where $f$ is not derivable, you obtain that the derivative of $f|_{\mathbb{R}\backslash E}$ is not bounded so this idea doesn't work.

You can use the definition but it gets long and tedious.

A good idea instead is to use Heine-Cantor theorem, for example in this way:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is clearly continuous so, by Heine-Cantor theorem, $f|_{[0,2\pi]}:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuosu, so
\begin{equation}
\forall \ \varepsilon>0 \ \exists \ \delta>0 : \ \forall \ x,y\in[0,2\pi]:|x-y|<\delta\text{ we have }|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{equation}
To extend the uniform continuity to all $\mathbb{R}$ it is sufficent to observe that if we choose $\delta<\pi$ then the condition $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $\exists \ n\in\mathbb{Z}:x,y\in[n\pi,n\pi+2\pi]$ so $x-n\pi\in[0,2\pi]$ and $y-n\pi\in[0,2\pi]$.

Now, since $|(x-n\pi)-(y-n\pi)|=|x-y|<\delta$ and $(x-n\pi),(y-n\pi)\in[0,2\pi]$, we can apply $(1)$ to get $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x-n\pi)-f(y-n\pi)|<\varepsilon$ where the last equality follows from the fact that $f$ is $\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Sir the period is 2pi ???

Answer (score 0):

Your function is periodic and continuous. This implies uniform continuity (Heine–Cantor theorem).